# Pasar variable a header

Tags: php, html, mvc

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy haciendo una app que usa el MVC desde php, lo primero que hago es cargar el header de la pagina lo que solo es hacer esto:

```
require_once 'header.php'
```

Eso lo hago en el index para que todas las páginas tengan el header, lo malo es que quiero cambiar la etiqueta `title` de la página, pero no se como hacer eso, ya que todos los archivos se cargan despues del header, y por la orden en el que se ejecutan no puedo cambiarlo, intente solo para ver si funcionaba usando la variable `SESSION` y crear esa variable mas tarde, y el header lo deje así:

```
  <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['title'])): ?>
    <title>Titulo</title>
  <?php else: ?>
    <title><?=$_SESSION['title']?></title>
  <?php endif ?>
```

Y despues en la página en la que quería cambiar el titulo solo creaba la variable de esta forma:

```
$_SESSION['title'] = "Otro titulo";
```

Pero tampoco se cambiar, ¿alguien me puede decir como puedo cambiar el valor de la variable y mostrarlo una vez cambiado el mismo valor? Espero haberme dado a entender. Desde ya gracias :).

Comment: Porque no creas una función en header.php y que este te devuelva el layout, luego cuando llamas a la función le pases el titulo como valor, algo como ```$layout = my_header($titulo);```, de esta manera podrás cambiar el titulo fácilmente en cada página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear fácilmente una función y pasarle a este el título como valor, de esta forma si deseas podrías pasar más valores y te evitas crear tantas sesiones.

**Posible ejemplo:**

*header.php*

```
function layoutHeader ($titulo) {
    echo "
        <head>
            <meta charset='utf-8'>
            <title>$titulo</title>
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='estilos.css'>
        </head>
    ";
}
```

En la página *index.php*

```
require_once 'header.php';
$layout = layoutHeader('Soy un nuevo titulo');
echo $layout;
```

**Alternativa**
Si deseas usar sesiones, te dejo una alternativa

*header.php*

```
<?php 
$titulo = (isset($_SESSION['title'])) ? $_SESSION['title'] : 'Titulo por defecto';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title><?php echo $titulo ?></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='estilos.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>Menu</nav>
```

En la página *index.php*

```
session_start();// Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente
// Creamos nuevo titulo
$_SESSION['title'] = 'nuevo titulo';// ¡importante! que vaya antes de incluir el header.php
require_once 'header.php';
```

Comment: pero por ejemplo en el header tengo toda la navbar y todo el head, entonces ¿ de esa forma tal vez estaría un poco  mas desordenado todo no?

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía ¿Porque? podrías simplemente crear otra función para tu menú en la página header.php y luego lo llamas donde quieras ```echo layoutMenu();```

Comment: DBE, tienez razon, creo que ya vi como adaptarlo, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada amigo, ahora te edito mi respuesta y te dejo una alternativa mediante sesiones también.

Comment: DBE esta bien, muchas gracias :)

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía ya te dejé un ejemplo alternativo usando una sesión, aunque yo personalmente usaría el método de crear funciones por separado y luego lo llamas donde quieras, un saludo.

Comment: DBE muchas gracias, veré cual de las dos me conviene en mi caso :). Igualmente un saludo